# Automapper: Null List<Object> to Null Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, mapping, automapper

I am trying to map a list which is null to an array with use of Automapper.
Whenever I am mapping the null list it is becoming an empty array.

I know I can use

```
cfg.AllowNullCollections; 
cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues;
```

but I do not want to change that globally.

Is there a way to exclusively apply this thing to a desired mapping I want ?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can set it per profile. You can put that one map in a separate profile.